# is it ok to define variables as nil if user is not signed in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have a conditional in a controller action that looks for whether or not a user is signed in. If they are, it sets three instance variables to an instance of `current_user`. If no one is signed in, then `current_user` doesn't exist, and I get a `no method error` unless I set those three variables to `nil`.

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
 def show
  if user_signed_in?
   @fruit = current_user.fruits.build
   @car = current_user.cars.build
   @building = current_user.buildings.find_by(item_id: @item.id)
  else
   @fruit = nil
   @car = nil
   @building = nil
  end
 end
end
```

I want the page to be viewable by people who aren't users, but worry that setting them to `nil` might be bad practice. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: setting nil value to instance variable does not make any difference, please share some context of no method error?

Comment: the error was `undefined method 'fruits' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Those aren't `global variables`.

Comment: @jvillain instance variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should avoid such assignment and modify action as,

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
 def show
  if user_signed_in?
   @fruit = current_user.fruits.build
   @car = current_user.cars.build
   @building = current_user.buildings.find_by(item_id: @item.id)
  end
 end
end
```

Now when user is not signed in then `@fruit`, `@car` and `@building` will be nil, no need to assigned nil value to these variables.